# search a prolog result list by second value of the result list

Tags: prolog

I use a findall predicate

```
findall(A,getzoo(B,A),MyList)
```

which returns this list

```
A = [[[ant,bear,crab,tortoise,lion],230], [[lion,tiger,bear],560], [[platypus,tiger,snake],3500], [[hippo,giraffe,snail,emu,condor],30], [[bat,robin,hawk,ape,macaw],100]]
```

I need to return the min from the list i.e. `Min = [hippo,giraffe,snail,emu,condor],30]`

and I have the min predicate working well on a straight list.

```
minList([H],H).  
minList([H|T],Min):-  minList(T,Next),  (H<Next, Min=H; H>=Next, Min=Next)
```

.

I was having problems trying to parse a structure [[[List],Number],[[List],Number],[[List],Number],...] and am unable to isolate the number.

This is the answer I was looking for .

```
findVal([[H,Val]|T],Val).
findVal([H|T],Out) :- findVal(T,Out).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your list items are two-element lists, you have to write a pattern that unifies with those and binds a variable to the second element. I.e.,

```
[_, Y]
```

for a single element to retrieve its second element and call it `Y`.

Then, the recursive clause for `minList` would become

```
minList([[X, Y] | T], Min) :-
    minList(T, MinT),
    % now pick apart MinT and compare Y with its right half
```

or

```
minList([H | T], Min) :-
    H = [X, Y],
    % proceed as before
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning patterns.